# Invalid Path while processing Font with MGCB

Tags: c#, monogame

I'm playing around with Monogame and can't add a font.
When adding a font with the MonoGame Pipeline tool i can't build my project anymore.

Visual studio stopps with the following error:

> Der Befehl
>   ""C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\MonoGame\v3.0\Tools\MGCB.exe"
>   /@:"C:\dev\Mini\Mini\Content\Content.mgcb" /platform:Windows
>   /outputDir:"C:\dev\Mini\Mini\Content\bin\Windows"
>   /intermediateDir:"C:\dev\Mini\Mini\Content\obj\Windows" /quiet" wurde
>   mit dem Code 1 beendet.
>   'FontDescriptionProcessor' had unexpected

(sorry, its German, but i think you can understand the problem ; ) )

When i execute the error throwing command i get a more helping error:

> C:\dev\Mini\Mini\Content>"C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\MonoGame\v3.0\Tools\MGCB.exe"
>   /@:"C:\dev\Mini\Mini\Content\Content.mgcb" /platform:Windows
>   /outputDir:"C:\dev\Mini\Mini\Content\bin\Windows"
>   /intermediateDir:"C:\dev\Mini\Mini\Content\obj\Windows" Build started
>   07.08.2015 23:15:43
>
> Skipping C:/dev/Mini/Mini/Content/Game/Character.PNG Skipping
>   C:/dev/Mini/Mini/Content/SplashScreen/splashScreenGame.png Skipping
>   C:/dev/Mini/Mini/Content/Game/Background.PNG
>   C:/dev/Mini/Mini/Content/fonts/default.spritefont
>   C:/dev/Mini/Mini/Content/fonts/default.spritefont: error: Processor
>   'FontDescriptionProcessor' had unexpected failure!
>   System.ArgumentException: Illegales Zeichen im Pfad.    bei
>   System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean
>   checkAdditional)    bei System.IO.Path.IsPathRooted(String path)
>   bei
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Processors.FontDescriptionProcessor.FindFontFileFromFontName(String
>   fontName, String fontDirectory)    bei
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Processors.FontDescriptionProcessor.Process(FontDescription
>   input, ContentProcessorContext context)    bei
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.ContentProcessor`2.Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.IContentProcessor.Process(Object
>   input, ContentProcessorContext context)    bei
>   MonoGame.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Builder.PipelineManager.ProcessContent(PipelineBuildEvent
>   pipelineEvent)Skipping
>   C:/dev/Mini/Mini/Content/SplashScreen/SplashScreen.xml Skipping
>   C:/dev/Mini/Mini/Content/Game/Game.xml
>
> Build 3 succeeded, 1 failed.
>
> Time elapsed 00:00:00.19.

I understand, that the path `C:/dev/Mini/Mini/Content/fonts/default.spritefont`
is invalid, but i don't see any invalid characters. The .spritefont file is generated with the MonoGame tool and not imported. Did i miss something?

I am on a Windows 10, the MonoGame Pipeline Tool is on version 3.5.0.465 and MGCB.exe has the version 3.5.0.465, too.

Edit: When checking the path myself, everything looks ok and moving the whole project to an other harddrive doesn't help at all.

Edit2: Okey. it looks like it is not my font path. It is the path loaded from the registry. The line `registryKey.GetValue(current).ToString();` inside the `FindFontFileFromFontName` method returns `ARIAL.TTF\00\0\0\0\0\0`. I will look into it and update this question or make an answer.

Comment: _Arial_ is **not** a re-distributable font for one thing.  http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/utility/font_pack

Comment: @MickyDuncan thank you. I'm not planning to redistribute this : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing around i came to an solution (or i found the problem...):
Some font paths in my registry are corrupted. Fonts with an uppercase Date value are throwing errors. When you encounter a similar problem take a look in your registry under `"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Fonts"`l, check your chosen font or change it to a different one. I hope this solution will help you, too. (And when somebody know, why my registry data got corrupted, please let me know.)

[image]

Comment: It sounds like the pipeline tool has a bug in it preventing it from handling these. I don't think the registry is to blame

Comment: @craftworkgames like i wrote in my question, the data of these fonts is `ARIAL.TTF\00\0\0\0\0\0`. It seems invalid for me, but i think cutting of these characters could solve the problem.

Comment: Those characters look like end of line markers. Maybe they are corrupt, but I wouldn't jump to any conclusions

Comment: Jear, but i will open a Issue on the github page.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and because the spritefont file is just a font meta-data definition file and not the actual font I still had manually install the TTF font files in Windows, then the build succeeded since the font could then be found to compress into the binary.